# How do you repair a vehicle?

Tags: arma-2, dayz-2012

I've come across various parts saying they are used to repair broken vehicles, however whenever I come across vehicles it doesn't seem I'm able to repair them.

Are only some vehicles able to be repaired, and if so, how can I tell if it can be repaired?

How can I tell what parts a vehicle needs be repaired?

How can I repair a vehicle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Repairing Vehicles

Vehicles are repaired by using the *replace parts* option accessible through the action menu if used on a vehicle.

Only some vehicles can be repaired (list below), and in order to repair them you need to replace all the broken/missing parts in the vehicle (list below). Every vehicle starts missing all of their parts, but it is possible to come across partially repaired vehicles (due to the work of other players). In order to replace parts you require a [toolbox](http://dayzwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Toolbox), and after the vehicle has been fully repaired it must be filled with fuel via a Jerry Can to work (the amount of fuel required depends on the vehicle).

### Repairable Vehicles

**Land**

[GAZ](http://dayzwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=GAZ)
[Offraod Pickup Truck](http://dayzwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Offroad_Pickup_Truck)
[Pickup Truck](http://dayzwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Pickup_Truck)
[Military Offroad](http://dayzwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Military_Offroad)
[Motorcycle](http://dayzwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Motorcycle)
[ATV](http://dayzwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=ATV)

**Air**

[UH-1H Huey](http://dayzwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=UH-1H_Huey)

**Sea**

[Fishing Boats](http://dayzwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Fishing_Boat)

### Required Items

[Engine Parts](http://dayzwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Engine_Parts)
[Fuel Tank Parts](http://dayzwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Fuel_Tank_Parts)
[Four Wheels](http://dayzwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Wheel)
[Scrap Metal](http://dayzwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Scrap_Metal)
[Windscreen Glass](http://dayzwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Windscreen_Glass) *(optional)*
[Toolbox](http://dayzwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Toolbox)
[Jerry Can](http://dayzwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Jerry_Can) *(amount required varies based on the vehicle)*